# Set visible view from ArrayList Adapter that resides in a separate file from the activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

excuse my java newbie jargon here (c# programmer) but I have an adapter in a separate file and a viewpager with three views (fragments) in my activity. Based on a button click that I handle in the adapter.java class like so

> > mHolder.gAnswerQuestion = (ImageView)
> >
> > mHolder.gAnswerQuestion.setOnClickListener(this);

the click listener is the adapter obviously. I think this is simple but i'm in a time crunch and dont want to spin my wheels on this one for too long.

mHolder.mediaView.findViewById(R.id.reply_to_challenge);
I need to change the viewpager's fragment. How do I get an instance of my mViewpager that I defined in the OnCreate() method so that I can do something like

> > mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

or some other arbitrary index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you pass the reference through the Adapter's constructor?

```
private ViewPager _viewPager;

public MyAdapter(ViewPager viewPager) {
    _viewPager = viewPager;
    //and use it on your listener
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple.Thanks valbertos.